# Divide PDF Page using C#

Tags: c#-3.0

I have A4 size PDF page. PDF page contains 10 images. I want to split the PDF page as 10 image files. Plz give me an Idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PDFBox (a library available for .NET) to convert each page of the PDF to a PNG image, then use the GDI functions in C# to copy known regions of the PNG files and save them as individual image files. This only works if the layout of the images on each page is static.

More info on PDFBox:

http://studentclub.ro/lucians_weblog/archive/2007/03/22/read-from-a-pdf-file-using-c.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[PDFsharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/) seems to be a popular open source choice for PDF manipulation from .NET and Mono. [PdfMod](http://live.gnome.org/PdfMod) is a related Mono-based front-end.